# ADC 'ADS1130' Wiring Problem

Tags: adc

I am hacking a commercial board which uses ADS1130 for analog to digital conversion. Wiring in commercial board is a bit different than what is specified in datasheet. In commercial board, Pin number 4 is connected to Pin nummber 1 i.e 4 is connected to VCC. But datasheet indicates that pin number 4 is DGND. And commercial board operates absolutely fine without any problem. I need to design a layout for my ADS1130 too. So whether or not to copy the commercial board layout, I am in great dilemma. [Here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1130.pdf) is the datasheet. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In commercial board, Pin number 4 is connected to Pin nummber 1 i.e 4
>   is connected to VCC. But datasheet indicates that pin number 4 is
>   DGND.

Then it can't be the chip you think it is. The data sheet is clear about pins 2, 3 and 4 - they are DGND: -

[image]

Of course you could have read the part number incorrectly when in fact it was an ADS1131 with pin 4 as an input: -

[image]

If you are trying to design something, the most important information you will get is the data sheet. Forget trying to hack a design and read the data sheet.

Comment: And after the data sheet the errata and the application notes where the explain the parts where the datasheet lied.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany well it's either "read the data sheet" or "hack an existing design" (of unknown origin and unknown performance)!

Comment: Yup.. considering there's no guarantee the 'existing design' was competent the choice is clear. Couldn't not disagree more.